# Отслеживание изменений записи в БД или как нормально использовать callback?

Tags: node.js, ооп, typescript, callback, knex.js

Всем привет, я новенький в typescript и очень сильно запутался в логике- прошу подсказать с решением проблемы: я реализовал класс с подключением к различным  СУБД (*SqlDatabaseService*) в нем я написал метод для отслеживания изменений в записи на вход я передаю запрос, время ожидания, и функцию что мы должны делать:

```
//Проверка, изменилась ли запись
  async trackRecordChanges(
    queryFunction: () => Promise<Record<string, any>>,
    timeout: number,
    callback: (changed: boolean, newRecord?: Record<string, any>) => void
  ): Promise<() => void> {
    let initialRecord: Record<string, any> | null = null;
  
    const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
      try {
        const newRecord = await queryFunction();
  
        if (!initialRecord) {
          initialRecord = newRecord;
          return;
        }
  
        const changed = !isEqual(initialRecord, newRecord);
        callback(changed, changed ? newRecord : undefined);
        
        // Если произошли изменения, останавливаем отслеживание
        if (changed) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking changes:', error);
      }
    }, timeout);
  
    // Возвращаем функцию для остановки отслеживания
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }
```

потом я решил написать функцию чтобы она упрощала отслеживание изменений по конкретной таблице:

```
    export async function trackPulseChanges(db: SqlDatabaseService, isbRC: number, timeStop: number): Promise<{ ANNOTAT: string | undefined; CONSISTS: string | undefined }> {
  return new Promise<{ ANNOTAT: string | undefined; CONSISTS: string | undefined }>(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let stopTracking: () => void;
      console.log("Запущена функция отслеживания");

      const queryFunction = async () => {   //данная запись 100 процентов работает 
        // Получаем новую запись со всеми столбцами
        const newRecord = await db.getSingleRecord({
          table: 'DOC_RC',
          conditions: {
            ISN_DOC: isbRC,
          },
          orderBy: {
            column: 'DOC_DATE',
            direction: 'desc' as 'desc',
          },
          limit: 1,
        });
        console.log(newRecord);
        return newRecord || {}; // Если записи нет, вернем пустой объект
      };

      // Отслеживаем изменения в записи и сохраняем функцию остановки
      stopTracking = await db.trackRecordChanges(queryFunction, timeStop, (changed, newRecord) => {
        if (changed) {
          // Останавливаем отслеживание
          stopTracking();
          console.log("Функция отслеживания завершена");
          resolve({
            ANNOTAT: newRecord?.ANNOTAT,
            CONSISTS: newRecord?.CONSISTS,
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Значение PULCE не изменилось. Повторная проверка через интервал времени");
        }
      });

      // Добавляем проверку на истечение времени
      setTimeout(() => {
        stopTracking();
        console.log("Время выполнения истекло. Функция отслеживания завершена.");
        reject(new Error("Время выполнения истекло."));
      }, timeStop);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Ошибка при проверке PULCE:', error);
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

но при вызове проверки данной функции: он выдает ошибку и даже не выводит мне элемент

```
    (async () => {
  try {
    const result = await trackPulseChanges(db, 4530, 50000);
    console.log('Изменение PULCE:');
    console.log('ANNOTAT:', result.ANNOTAT);
    console.log('CONSISTS:', result.CONSISTS);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Ошибка:', error);
  } finally {
     db.knex.destroy()
     console.log(22222)
  }
  console.log(1111111111111111111111111)
})();
```

вот вывод консоли:

```
Запущена функция отслеживания
Время выполнения истекло. Функция отслеживания завершена.
Ошибка: Error: Время выполнения истекло.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\Extensions\DB\SqlRequests.ts:73:16)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
22222
1.1111111111111111e+24
Error executing query: Error: aborted
    at PendingOperation.abort (D:\\node_modules\tarn\dist\PendingOperation.js:25:21)
    at D:\\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:208:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at D:\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:207:53
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Client_MSSQL.destroy (D:\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:358:9)
Error fetching single record: Error: aborted
    at PendingOperation.abort (D:\\node_modules\tarn\dist\PendingOperation.js:25:21)
    at D:\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:208:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at D:\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:207:53
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Client_MSSQL.destroy (D:\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:358:9)
Error checking changes: Error: aborted
    at PendingOperation.abort (D:\\node_modules\tarn\dist\PendingOperation.js:25:21)
    at D:\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:208:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at D:\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:207:53
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Client_MSSQL.destroy (D:\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:358:9)
```

мне кажется я впадаю в некую рекурсию тк методы callbackа мне мало знакомы, прошу подсказать куда смотреть чтобы исправить ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции trackRecordChanges используется setInterval, что означает вызовы функции через заданный интервал до остановки, особенность в том что функция перед первым выполнением колбэка подождет заданный интервал.

в trackPulseChanges используется setTimeout с тем же значением timeStop, что означает через заданное время выполнение функции.

Для примера если я поставлю timeStop равный 5сек, setInterval начнет слать запросы каждые 5 сек, но подождав первые 5сек. Как только начнет отрабатывать первый запрос в БД (через 5сек), setTimeout также отработает, т.к. и для него истек таймаут. Следовательно все тут же отменяется.

По логике должно быть 2 timeout, допустим 5сек и 60сек, первый нужен для setInterval чтобы отправлять запрос каждые 5 сек, а второй для setTimeout чтобы прекратить их слать через минуту